# Image upload and rename with django

Tags: python, django, image-uploading

I'm having trouble getting this to work:

```
def _get_image_name(filename):
    return 'asdf'


class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    file = forms.ImageField(upload_to=_get_image_name)
```

When running this, I'm getting "**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to'". My django version is 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Johannes Charra said - forms.ImageField doesn't have param upload_to. I solved my problem by adding a `clean_file` method in which I changed the `InMemoryUploadedFile` name attribute.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code for renaming an `InMemoryUploadedFile`

Answer (score 2):

The `upload_to` parameter is for `models.ImageField` only. The `forms.ImageField` you're using works differently. You find its documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield).